# get value of session from one module controller to another module controller in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

create session in my default module controller like

```
 $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('MyNamespace');    
   $session->user_store_id = $store_id;
```

when i want to get this session value in my admin module controller like

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('MyNamespace');   
    echo $session->user_store_id;
```

get null value.But in default module when i try to get session value it return value;

Comment: Have you testet whether the session is always the same? `echo session_id();`

Comment: 'in my default module controller' - Can you clarify **where** the variable is set? - If it is within a controller, a new session would need to dispatch that controller first before the variable is available.

Comment: i create a simple  session for test $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('foo');
        $ns->foo = 'bar'; and in admin module try to get it like $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('foo'); echo $ns->foo; but still get null